# Convert PDF to HTML to get bold and font size in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pdf

I want to get bold and size of text from pdf, but I can't extract such information from pdf.

So, I want to convert pdf to html in python and I have tried every possible library which I know but none is working perfectly, my format is getting disturb in every library. I  have tried pdfminer.six, pdf2htmlEX and many more but none is giving output in proper format. I know this question has been asked previously so many times but none is working perfectly for me as of now.

PDF link: https://github.com/sahib-s/Heading-Detection-PDF-Files/blob/master/1.pdf

Problem: In pdf very first page COURSE OBJECTIVE is in single line but after converting, it's splitting up in different tags. I'm having similar problem everywhere. I want to get headings in same tags.

Comment: Do you have a pdf as an example? Also share your actual output and the desired output.

Comment: you can use "pdfminer" library in python. Using this convert you pdf to xml. this xml will have the font information.